# [Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client.TeamFoundationServerFactory]::GetServer specify credentials

Tags: powershell, command-line, tfs, powershell-2.0

I have following code for connection to TFS:

```
$tfs = [Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client.TeamFoundationServerFactory]::GetServer($serverName)
```

How I can specify my login and pass as parameter here? By default it use account under which the script is running, but I would like to set different one

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out [this blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/buckh/archive/2006/09/14/factory-vs-constructor.aspx) - the TeamFoundationServerFactory API is not designed to support custom credentials.  You should use the TeamFoundationServer class constructor, instead.

```
$creds = Get-Credential
$server = New-Object Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client.TeamFoundationServer $url,$creds.GetNetworkCredential()
```